# TypeScript narrow down keyof to a literal value

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

In the following code

```
const foo = <T extends object>(
  option: T,
  key: keyof T,
) => {
  return option[key];
};
```

How can I narrow down the return type to a correct type of the returned value.
I mean in the following example, I would like to have `number` as type of `x` and `string` as type of `y`. Currently both have `number|string` as type

```
const option = {a: 1, b: 'c'}

const x = foo(option,'a')
const y = foo(option,'b')
```

Comment: Use another generic parameter

Comment: Ok, got it `<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(
  option: T,
  key: K,
)`